# Render Picker Items from React-Native picker to populate drop-menu selections

Tags: reactjs, react-native-picker

I am successfully using the `react-native` picker to render a drop-menu in one of my components. Right now, in the picker code I am hardcoding the values used to populate the drop-menu items. What I'd ideally like to do is pass these in as props, and have them dynamically generate as many items as necessary within the `picker`. I'm not sure how to do that, though. I tried using a for-loop but I can't run that kind of conditional logic within the component code itself. This is what it looks like with hard coded values.

```
export const DropDownMenu = (props) => {
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState(null);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Picker
        selectedValue={selectedValue}
        style={{ height: 50, width: 150 }}
        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
          props.onSelectMenuValue(itemValue), 
          setSelectedValue(itemValue)
        }}
      >
        <Picker.Item label="A" value="a" />
        <Picker.Item label="B" value="b" />
        <Picker.Item label="C" value="c" />
      </Picker>
    </View>
  );
}
```

How could I render `Picker.Item` values based on the props passed in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an `options` prop as an array of objects with a `label` and a `value` property and use `map` like this:

```
<Picker /*whatever you need for picker here*/>
{props.options.map(option => <Picker.Item label={option.label} value={option.value}/>)}
</Picker>
```